# How can I use my GPU to provide AI-powered code completion/translation/generation?

Tags: ide, artificial-intelligence, code-generation, api-design

I'm interested in using new large language models to help me program.

I have access to GPUs that can be used to run models. I have experience running text generation locally for English. I know that code-focused models like PolyCoder and CodeT5 are available in manageable sizes for single-machine inference. I know how to install a Vim code completion extension, and even got set up with TabNine's hosted AI completion service.

How can I glue these together so that I can do AI-assisted programming without sending my code outside my organization? Is there an emerging or de facto standard for a remote code completion/assistance API that I would have to implement, or that someone else has already implemented, on top of e.g. the Transformers Python API used to run PolyCoder?